# JQuery не работает

Tags: jquery

С jQuery работаю не в первый день. Но тут у меня возникла проблема. Он не работает. Все делаю по-прежнему. Но видимо что то есть и я никак этого не замечаю. Помогите разобраться. Подключаю так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jScript.js"></script>
```

Внутри:

```
 $('#gallery_grid').css({
'height' : '100px',
'width' : '100px',
'background-color' : '#0F0'
 });
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="gallery_grid"></div>
```

Укажите, где проблема? Почему не работает? Я чет не вижу

Comment: `$(document).ready(...)`?

Comment: нет, дело не в этом. Я даже alert ставлю, он тоже не работает. Да и я никогда раньше его не ставил, но он работал

Comment: @navi1893: В отладчике есть исключения? Уверенны что файл вообще грузиться и что кодировка файла верная?

Answer (score 1):

в src лучше пишите полный путь к файлу, а не относительный, как у вас. И потом не будет таких проблем.

```
<script src="http://localalo4ka.ru/jQuery.js">
```

Comment: Всегда пишу от корня и никаких проблем.